# How to send updated data from java program to NiFi?

Tags: apache-nifi

I have micro-services running and when a web user update data in DB using micro-service end-points, I want to send updated data to NiFi also. This data contains updated list of names, deleted names, edited names etc. How to do it? which processor I have to use from NiFi side?

I am new to NiFi. I am yet to try anything from my side. I am reading google documents which can guide me.

No source code is written. I want to start it. But I will share here once I write it.

Expected result is NiFi should get updated list of names and NiFi should refer updated list for generating required alerts/triggers etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually do it in lots of ways. MQ, Kafka, HTTP(usinh [ListenHTTP](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.6.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ListenHTTP/)). Just deploy the relevant one to you and configure it, even listen to a directory(using [ListFile](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ListFile/index.html) & [FetchFile](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.FetchFile/index.html)). 
You can connect NiFi to pretty much everything, so just choose how you want to connect your micro services to NiFi.

Comment: Ben Yaakobi, yes I am using Kafka to send data to NiFi. NiFi needs to compare this data against list of names stored at NiFi Side. Every time, list of names gets updated in real time mode we need to send it back to NiFi. There is web application which modifies names. We have micro-services running which is used by web application. Whenever user updates name(s) we need to immediately send it back to NiFi. I want like to know how can I do this part? which processor shall I use at NiFi side? which APIs I should use at Java side?

Comment: The answer is right, you can use whatever method in the list, which is going to be better depends on your architecture.

Comment: So just use `ConsumeKafka` for the relevant version you use.

Comment: ConsumeKafka is to receive messages from Kakfa Topic. These messages will be processed by NiFi using various processor and various checking takes place. During the checking, we need updated list of names. Names can be changed any point of time and in real time mode these updated names must be sent to NiFi processor which is doing this checking part. This is my need. If someone can give me some tips it would help me a lot. I am pretty new with Apache NiFi. Thanks.